# Using apply() to chain constructors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, apply

I'm learning `apply()` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_to_chain_constructors), there's an example I can't figure out:

```
// Create constructor method for array of args
Function.prototype.construct = function(aArgs) {
  var oNew = Object.create(this.prototype);
  this.apply(oNew, aArgs);
  return oNew;
};
```

what does `this.apply(oNew, aArgs)` do?

Comment: The first argument in apply is the scope and the second, and subsequent arguments, are the parameters being passed to the function which you're applying.

Comment: @Baruch Actually, the first argument to apply is the binding, not the scope. Scope is a completely different concept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: what would be the aim of this function?

### The aim

This prototype function `constructor` is defined to provide an alternative to `new`. Where `new Person(a,b)` will need the arguments as such, this function provides a way to pass those arguments as array.

<sup>*As a side note: it should be said that the spread syntax makes such a feature unnecessary, as we can pass such an array like so: `new Person(...[a,b])`. But OK...*</sup>

### Example use

Let's say we have a constructor:

```
function Person(name, gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}
```

And I have an array with the arguments:

```
var args = ["Helen", "F"];
```

Then we *could* do:

```
var person = new Person(args[0], args[1]);
```

But we want to pass `args` as single argument. Now this prototype function will help us with that. We can now do:

```
var person = Person.construct(args);
```

```js
// Create constructor method for array of args
Function.prototype.construct = function(aArgs) {
  var oNew = Object.create(this.prototype);
  this.apply(oNew, aArgs);
  return oNew;
};

function Person(name, gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}

var args = ["Helen", "F"];

var person = Person.construct(args);

console.log(person);
```

#### How does it work

When calling `Person.construct(args)` the `this` object will be `Person`, i.e. our constructor function.

Then the following is done:

```
var oNew = Object.create(this.prototype);
```

This will create a `Person` object, but without actually *calling* the constructor function `Person`, so the object is not initialised. It is just an empty object that is an instance of `Person`.

So we need somehow to call `Person` with the arguments we have. We can use `apply` for that:

```
this.apply(oNew, aArgs);
```

Recall that `this` is `Person`, so we call `Person` here via `apply`. `apply` makes it possible to call a function with a specific `this` object value (our newly created instance of `Person`) and the arguments as an array -- exactly what we need.

So the above will initialise our empty object with the `name` and `gender` arguments, completing the full creation and initialisation that you would normally have with `new`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and splendid explanation! I think the key point here is the customized `construct()` will always be used with ordinary constructor function like `Foo.construct()` so `this` will refer to `Foo`.

Comment: Best explain ever !!
Its the demo code from @trincot make all things easier for our brain, thanks u very much

Answer (score 1):

This function is works like the operator `new` in Javascript.
You can figure out how `new` works in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)
For example, if you define an constructor function like below

```js
function Foo(name, age) {
  this.name = name
  this.age = age
}

Foo.prototype.hello = function() {
  console.log('hello' + this.name + this.age)
}
```

If you already define the `Function.prototype.construct` like the example you show.
Then you can use either `const a = new Foo('a', 1)` or `const a = Foo.construct('a', 1)` to create the same object

And `this.apply(oNew, aArgs)` is used for call the constructor function to initiate the instance just created

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort buddy! Much appreciated.